# Why can't read_csv use my directory/path?

Tags: r

I am having a problem with my read_csv. I have used this function with no problem but the path/directory I am using is a little different than normal and I can't figure it out by myself.
This is the code I have been using:

```
X2022_03_08_habit_and_OCD_clinical <- read_csv("Box/OCD: Habit or Learning?/experiment/data/raw/survey-data/2022-03-08_habit-and-OCD_clinical.csv")
```

I have tired tweaking this by not using the first two arguments with no luck. Has anyone used Box in a path before (Box is in my finder, like desktop would be). I also tried updating r for that first error code but maybe it didn't take, I am not sure how to update again.
Here is the error code I have been receiving:[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz6qC.png)

I would appreciate any help and I apologize if there is a simple answer I have been missing!

Comment: That isn't an error; that's a warning. It's telling you that a column didn't have a name and function assigned a name for you.

Comment: Okay thank you! Do you how I can fix this?

Comment: once you read the csv file, you can change the name of the column as you wish using for example colnames().

Comment: Have you checked `getwd()` ? The `.csv` file might be outside the working directory.

Comment: Thank you. I used this function and got "Users/claireamberrammel/" I tried to use this is the read_csv but it still did not work, any other ideas?